# Using "Not In" statement in sql for a duplicated key

Tags: sql, sql-server

My question is:

Have an sql stored procedure which brings me a list of free rooms between two date in an hotel_reservation table for a given `hotelid` and `bookin` ,`bookout` dates.

Here is the procedure :

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcedure1
    (
    @DateStart date,
    @DateEnd date,
    @hotel_id int
    )

AS
    SELECT DISTINCT room_type_id, room_id
    FROM Room
WHERE room_id NOT IN (
        SELECT room_id
        FROM Hotel_Reservation
        WHERE @DateStart BETWEEN bookingStart AND bookingEnd
    OR @DateEnd BETWEEN bookingStart AND bookingEnd
    or bookingStart BETWEEN @DateStart AND @DateEnd  
    or bookingEnd BETWEEN @DateStart AND @DateEnd
    and hotel_id = @hotel_id 
) and hotel_id = @hotel_id 
    RETURN
```

Definition of `Room` table :

```
room_id          int
hotel_id         int
room_type_id     varchar
price            money
room_description varchar
```

In room table I used duplicated key with `room_id` and `Hotel_id` cause Hotel with id 201 can have `room_id` 101 also Hotel with id 202 can have `room_id` 101 to avoid from repeated columns I used this.

definition of `hotel_reservation table`

```
reservation_id int
customer_id    varchar
bookingStart   date
bookingEnd     date
status         varchar
room_id        int
hotel_id       int
date           date
```

The Problem is:

When I run this procedure If a user booked a room with id 101 at hotel 201, another user cant see the room with id 101 at hotel with id 202. It books all the 101 id rooms from the hotels.

How can I improve my procedure to overcome this problem?

Thanks for viewing..

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqbIG.jpg), [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmBOf.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to NOT EXSTS which allows multiple conditions?

In this case it can check *both* hotel *and* room ids.

```
SELECT DISTINCT room_type_id, room_id
FROM Room R
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM Hotel_Reservation H
        WHERE
    (
    @DateStart BETWEEN H.bookingStart AND H.bookingEnd
    OR @DateEnd BETWEEN H.bookingStart AND H.bookingEnd
    or H.bookingStart BETWEEN @DateStart AND @DateEnd  
    or H.bookingEnd BETWEEN @DateStart AND @DateEnd
    )
    and  --here is where we check **that room for that hotel**
    H.hotel_id = R.hotel_id and H.room_id = R.room_id
) 
and 
R.hotel_id = @hotel_id
```

Edit:

Thank you to Andriy M for correcting my AND/OR operator precedence with some brackets

Comment: Renmove the last "R.hotel_id = @hotel_id" condition then maybe. It's hard to tell without sample data

Comment: All the ORed conditions should be bracketed. And by the way, just two of them are sufficient: `@DateStart BETWEEN H.bookingStart AND H.bookingEnd or H.bookingStart BETWEEN @DateStart AND @DateEnd` (I mean, just two of the *four date checks*. The joining condition is needed too, of course.)

Comment: Thank for your helps that works good when I bracketed the ORs.

Comment: @Andriy M: Lordy, how did I miss that? Thank you. [/facepalm]

Comment: @Recep I'm glad it worked.  Don't forget to mark it answered!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick run at a possible solution.  (sorry i didn't have time to test it...)

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcedure1 (    
     @DateStart date,    
     @DateEnd date,    
     @hotel_id int    
)
AS    

;WITH BookedRooms ( roomID )
AS (
    SELECT room_id        
    FROM Hotel_Reservation        
    WHERE hotel_id = @hotel_id
      AND ( @DateStart BETWEEN bookingStart AND bookingEnd    
         or @DateEnd BETWEEN bookingStart AND bookingEnd )
    )
SELECT DISTINCT room_type_id, room_id    
FROM Room
WHERE room_id NOT IN (
    SELECT room_id        
    FROM BookedRooms 
    ) 
and hotel_id = @hotel_id     

RETURN
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. If Is there any existing reservation for an hotel then code returns no result. When there is no reservation it returns the all available room ids.